# Smarty: cannot replace string

Tags: php, smarty

I'm new to Smarty and I have a variable which contains a URL http://someurl.com and I'm trying to perform a replace operation on it, to show http://m.someurl.com. This is what I have, but it's not working.

```
{$theurl | replace: 'http://' :'http://m.'}
```

I also tried assigning the $theurl to a second variable and perform the replacement there, but I have no luck.

I also tried escaping the slashes, replacing http for xxx, and nothing works.

I took a look here for reference: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give us some more information on the variable itself? How about you use a var_dump to show the current value of the variable:

```
{$theurl|var_dump}
```

Why are you using spaces in the smarty syntax, maby that is the problem:

```
{$theurl|replace:'http://':'http://m.'}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, nor Smarty. In a decent language (or Framework) spaces don't matter. Thanks anyway, I figured out that the problem was caused by the innocent spaces. Accepting your answer since it the solution for my problem.